# How to combine passport with routing-controller?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, jwt, passport.js

I'm currently trying to implement passport-ldap and passport-jwt to my rest API. For routing I use [pleerock/routing-controllers](https://github.com/pleerock/routing-controllers#using-authorization-features), which has a way for authorization, but it works with booleans and passport works with I honestly don't know. I'm not even sure if its possible to combine the two.

Currently AuthorizationChecker returns false because I don't know how to make passport.authenticate into a boolean.

```
useExpressServer(app, {
controllers: [UserController, IssueController, LoginController],
authorizationChecker: async (action: Action) => {
     return false;
}
@Authorized()
@Get("/test")
test(@Res() response: Response){
    response.send("Test done.")
}
```

How to use `passport.authenticate()` with routing-controlls authorization?

Comment: Did you come up with a solution to this? I'm trying to do the same. I'm thinking global middleware for this, using passport-jwt.

Comment: @ØysteinAmundsen i edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It's possible to combine passport with routing-controller.

The easiest way is to use passport as middleware with `@UseBefore` decorator before controllers classes or route methods:

```js
@JsonController()
@UseBefore(passport.authenticate('jwt'))
export class MyController { ... }
```

However you may want to use `@Authorized()` decorator. It little bit more complicated, but can be done with `authorizationChecker` configuration:

```js
import express from 'express';
import { Action, useExpressServer } from 'routing-controllers';

const app = express();

useExpressServer(app, {
  authorizationChecker: (action: Action) => new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
    passport.authenticate('jwt', (err, user) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      if (!user) {
        return resolve(false);
      }
      action.request.user = user;
      return resolve(true);
    })(action.request, action.response, action.next);
  }),
  currentUserChecker: (action: Action) => action.request.user,
});
```

Then you'll be able to use both @Authorized() and @CurrentUser decorators.

Check [passport authenticate](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/) and [routing-controllers auth features](https://github.com/typestack/routing-controllers#using-authorization-features) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

To use `authenticate()` you have to use it as a Middleware. Here is the [link](https://github.com/pleerock/routing-controllers#using-middlewares) on routing-controllers how to use Middleware. For the authenticationChecker

```
import * as jwt from 'jwt-simple'; 

currentUserChecker: async (action: Action) => {
        const token = action.request.headers["authorization"];
        console.log(token)
        let key= jwt.decode(token, "Banana");
        console.log(key)
        let user = await mongoose.model("users").findOne({'key': key.key});
        if (user != null && token != null) return user;
    }
```

This is a set up for jwt authentication with passport-jwt

Comment: Would it be possible to shared the whole code of the routing-controllers middleware ?

Comment: sadly not anymore